# how open flyout on textbox get focus?using uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am new in uwp.i have to create calculator using flyout feature.

how to open flyout below the textbox on textbox got focus.

Answer (score 1):

I used TextBlock instead of Textbox, but you can change that:

```
<TextBlock Text="Textblock with MenuFlyout" Height="20" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" x:Name="MyTextBlock">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="Flyout">
            <MenuFlyout.Items>
                <MenuFlyoutItem>
                    Click Me
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
            </MenuFlyout.Items>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

The Code behind the TextBlock_Tapped event:

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Flyout.ShowAt(MyTextBlock);
}
```

Comment: This will not work for `TextBox`es, which the original question asked. TextBoxes in UWP [do not fire the Tapped event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped?view=winrt-22621#controls-that-do-not-raise-the-tapped-event). `GotFocus`, recommended below, is a slightly better (albeit buggy) approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
GotFocus="TextBlock_Tapped"
```